# GitHub action docker/build-push-action@v4 with a simple test failing online, "works on my PC"?

Tags: docker, github-actions

Locally, with this `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine as node_builder
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the assets folder if exists
COPY assets assets
```

On my machine, I can test if asset is copied and it works (it's there):

```
$ touch assets/foo.js
$ docker build . -t node_builder:latest --target node_builder
$ docker run --rm node_builder:latest sh -c "stat assets/foo.js"
```

When i try to do the same with my online repository and `test.yml` workflow, asset `foo.js` is not copied. My Steps are described as:

```yml
node_builder:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
        # Clone this repository
        - name: Checkout
          uses: actions/checkout@v3

        # Just touch a new assets in the cloned repository
        - name: Create a simple asset
          run: touch assets/foo.js

        # Asset assets/foo.js is present OK!
        - name: Debug
          run: ls -la assets

        # Build the target image
        - name: Build target
          uses: docker/build-push-action@v4
          with:
              target: node_builder
              tags: node_builder:latest

        # Run the comand inside the image
        - name: Test assets copy
          run: docker run --rm node_builder:latest sh -c "stat assets/foo.js"
```

I'm trying to find out why using debug/echoing stuff but I can't find what I'm doing wrong (and for sure I'm missing something).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Be careful because any file mutation in the steps that precede the build step will be ignored, including processing of the .dockerignore file since the context is based on the Git reference. However, you can use the Path context using the context input alongside the actions/checkout action to remove this restriction.

Turns out `docker/build-push-action@v4` builds the GitHub repoository URL. So the solution is:

```
    # Build the target image
    - name: Build target
      uses: docker/build-push-action@v4
      with:
          target: node_builder
          context: .
          tags: node_builder:latest
```